# Equality and identity of indiscernibles

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm considering a first-order theory where there is a given binary relation symbol "=" and these axioms (the second one is a axiom schema) :
$$\forall x : x = x$$
$$\forall x, y : x=y \rightarrow (F(x) \leftrightarrow F(y))$$
Of course this looks like first-order logic with equality, but I'm looking for examples of models of these axioms where the interpretation of "=" is **not** the identity relation.

Let's notice that the axioms here imply those of an equivalence relation, but not the converse. What I'm looking for is an interpretation of "=" which is "stricter" than an equivalence relation, but still is not the identity.

I've read some reflexions on the subject (Black's article *The Identity of Indiscernibles*), but I'd like some mathematical examples, if there are any.

Comment: See discussion in Derek Goldrei, [Propositional and Predicate Calculus : A Model of Argument (Springer, 2005)](https://books.google.it/books?id=edqwSVJ9GGQC&pg=PA247), **Ch.5.4 The equality axioms and non-normal structures**.